# How to change file permissions on a remote server using python

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I'm writing a file to a remote server using python's library 'Paramiko'. I want to set file permission as I write files to the remote server.

Currently, I'm writing the file first and then trying to change it's permissions using 'chmod()' as shown in the paramiko documentation page. However, I do not see any changes in the file permissions after executing my code. Below is my code.

```
import paramiko

host='myhost'
user='myuser'
pw='mypassword'
localfilepath='mylocalpath'
remotefilepath='myremotepath'

ssh_client=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(hostname=host,username=user,password=pw)
sftp_client=ssh_client.open_sftp()

#writing file to remote server
sftp_client.put(localfilepath,remotefilepath)

#changing file permissions
sftp_client.chmod(remotefilepath, 0o600)
```

After running the above code, I'm successfully able to write file to the server, however the file permissions remain the same.

Before: '-rwxrwxrwx 1 myuser enduser    3928 Jul 30 13:11 test.csv\n'

After: '-rwxrwxrwx 1 myuser enduser    3928 Jul 30 13:11 test.csv\n'

Please advise. Thank you!

Comment: I would try reproducing the chmod problem with a command line sftp client. `sftp myuser@myhost`

Comment: @ColeTierney thanks for your quick response. Could you please elaborate on that? I'm totally new to this. A little detailed explanation/reference/code-snippet would help a lot. Thank you.

Comment: After you run the sftp command, you'll have an interactive prompt very similar to bash. Type help and you'll see a list of available commands.

Comment: I added an example as an answer . Not really an answer, but will hopefully help you narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 1):

An sftp command line client example for trouble shooting:

```
sftp myuser@myhost (enter password)
Connected to myhost.
sftp> help
Available commands:
bye                                Quit sftp
cd path                            Change remote directory to 'path'
chgrp [-h] grp path                Change group of file 'path' to 'grp'
chmod [-h] mode path               Change permissions of file 'path' to 'mode'
chown [-h] own path                Change owner of file 'path' to 'own'
df [-hi] [path]                    Display statistics for current directory or
                                   filesystem containing 'path'
    ...

sftp> ls -l testfile
-rwxrwxrwx    ? 1428     1434            0 Jul 30 17:46 testfile
sftp> chmod 600 testfile
Changing mode on /home/myuser/testfile
sftp> ls -l testfile
-rw-------    ? 1428     1434            0 Jul 30 17:46 testfile
sftp> exit
```

In my case `chmod 600` worked. If you still get the same results, then the problem is related to sftp. Maybe a uname or sftp configuration problem.

Comment: Hello @Cole! I have tried doing the below.


`ssh_client=paramiko.SSHClient()`
`ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())`
`ssh_client.connect(hostname=host,username=user,password=pw)`
`cmd = "cd /dev/data/;chmod 0o660 testfile.csv;ls -ltr"`
`stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh_client.exec_command(cmd)`
`stdout=stdout.readlines()`
`stdout = "".join(stdout)`
`print(stdout)`

I'm able to execute the above commands without an errors. However, in the output, the file permissions have not changed.

Comment: Can you try the sftp command line example just to double check? It would decouple paramiko from the test.